# IBM MobileFirst 7.1 - Where can I get the source code for Administrative Service and operations console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Where can I get the source code for Administrative Service and Operations console. We do have the license for the MFP 7.1 if that is not available open source.

Answer (score 1):

The console is proprietary materials of IBM. The fact you are an IBM customer with a license to use MobileFirst Platform Foundation does not mean you are entitled to the source... of any part of it. It is not open source.

Why do you need this source?

Comment: Specially for MFP Administrative services if I have the source code  I can debug and find out what fails and at what point this way I can have better understanding and control of how to use the services.

Comment: I think you should open a PMR - support ticket.

Comment: Can you guide me how can I create a PMR.